# Ratingbar is showing a black overlay in gridview

Tags: android, xml, gridview, ratingbar

I am trying to show a rating bar in my gridview rows but there is always a black overlay on top of the rating bars. If I have only 1 row my grid view then the rating bar is showing perfectly fine. But when I have multiple rows in my gridview then there is always a black overlay on top of the rating bar. So how do i solve this problem? And it seems to be happening only on lollipop devices. My code is given below:

My Gridview:

```
<UI.ExpandableHeightGridView
                android:id="@+id/gridview_agent_reviews"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
                android:isScrollContainer="false"
                android:numColumns="1"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />
```

My gridview row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0.5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:background="#cccccc" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/img_review_flag"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/img_review_flag"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lbl_review_date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="2016-04-05"
            android:typeface="sans" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="|"
            android:typeface="sans" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lbl_review_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="Recommendation by John Doe"
            android:typeface="sans" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_review_flag"
        android:layout_width="22dp"
        android:layout_height="22dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_flag_blue" />
</RelativeLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0.5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="#cccccc" />

<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/rate_review"
    style="@style/CustomRatingBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:isIndicator="true" />

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0.5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="#cccccc" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lbl_review_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Congrats! Keep up the great work."
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:typeface="sans" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And my getView in my Adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View v = view;
    ViewHolder holder;
    try {

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_list_agent_review, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.lblReviewDate = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lbl_review_date);
            holder.lblReviewer = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lbl_review_name);
            holder.lblReviewDesc = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lbl_review_text);
            holder.ReviewRate = (RatingBar) v.findViewById(R.id.rate_review);
            v.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }

        String []Date=list.get(i).CreateDate.split("T");
        holder.lblReviewDate.setText(Date[0]);
        holder.lblReviewer.setText("Recommendation by "+list.get(i).FirstName+" "+list.get(i).LastName);
        holder.lblReviewDesc.setText(list.get(i).RecommendationInfo);
        holder.ReviewRate.setRating(Float.valueOf(list.get(i).RatingScale));

    }catch (Exception e){


    }

    return v;
}
```

And a screenshot of the problem:

**GridView with multiple rows**

[image: GridView with multiple rows]

**GridView with 1 row**

[image: GridView with 1 row]

**Edit**

My style xml:

```
<style name="CustomRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/ratingbarcustom</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">32dip</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">32dip</item>
</style>
```

ratingbarcustom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@android:id/background"
    android:drawable="@drawable/rating_bar_empty" />
<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/rating_bar_empty" />
<item android:id="@android:id/progress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/rating_bar_filled" />
</layer-list>
```

ratingbarempty.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/star_outline" android:state_pressed="true" android:state_window_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/star_outline" android:state_focused="true" android:state_window_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/star_outline" android:state_selected="true" android:state_window_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/star_outline"/>
</selector>
```

ratingbarfull.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/star_full" android:state_pressed="true"     android:state_window_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/star_full" android:state_focused="true" android:state_window_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/star_full" android:state_selected="true" android:state_window_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/star_full"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: please share  your  style.xml

Comment: @PradeepGupta I've updated my question. Please take a look.

Comment: there is no need to use selector for select and unselect the Rating Bar. you have to just set your image in ratingbarcustom.xml

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@android:id/background"
    android:drawable="@drawable/star_outline" />
<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/star_outline" />
<item android:id="@android:id/progress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/star_full" />
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Didn't work. There is still the black overlay in my rating bar for multiple rows. BTW I've tested on genymotion emulator with api level 16 and the ratingbar is showing perfectly fine. But on a real device there is a black overlay.